# Django customise Default Group model

Tags: python, django, models

I m fairly new to Django and I want customise Django's default Group model with my own requirements,

Default django's Group model look like this:

```
class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_('name'), max_length=80, unique=True)
    permissions = models.ManyToManyField(
        Permission,
        verbose_name=_('permissions'),
        blank=True,
    )
```

I want to add a new field and make name field and that new field as one composite primary key.

Is there anyway this could be done?

Any suggestions would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an approach to solve your problem:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group


# inherit from Group instead of copy the code...
class Group(Group):
    new_field =  = models.CharField(
        verbose_name=('new-field'),
        max_length=31,
    )

    class Meta:
        indexes = [
            models.Index(fields=['last_name', 'first_name'], name='mixed_idx'),
        ]
```

[Read more](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/options/#django.db.models.Options.indexes) about the `indexs` option. (alias `index_together`).